# Translate R code into Python with Chaining Pipeline

Tags: python, r

I have a piece of R code that manipulates the iris dataset using the dplyr package, and I'm trying to achieve the same results in Python using a similar chaining pipeline approach. Here's the R code I want to translate:

```
 iris %>%
  select(-Petal.Width) %>%  #drops column Ptela.Width
  filter(Petal.Length > 2 | Sepal.Width > 3.1) %>% #Selects only rows where Criteria is met
  filter(Species %in% c('setosa', 'virginica')) %>% #Filters in Species selected
  mutate_if(is.numeric, scale) %>% #Numerical columns are scale into z-scores
  mutate(item = rep(1:3, length.out = n())) %>%  # a new col item is created and will carry the sequence 1,2,3 until the end of the dataste
  group_by(Species) %>% #groups by species
  summarise(n = n(), #summarises the size of each group
            n_sepal_over_1z = sum(Sepal.Width > 1), #counts the number of obs where Spepal.Width is over 1 z score
            nunique_item_petal_over_2z = n_distinct(item[Petal.Length>1]))
            #counst the unique elements in the col item where the values of the col Petal.length is over 1 z-score
```

I'm looking for a Python equivalent using libraries like Pandas and NumPy that would allow me to achieve the same results with a similar chaining or piping approach. How can I rewrite this R code into Python code to achieve the same results in one chunk of code?

Comment: Please do not ask exactly the same question twice.